# Best practise for getting access to the app instance

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, nestjs

I'm creating a NestJS app with Firebase cloud functions. I have to use both `onRequest` and `onCreate` (Firestore Events) from Firebase in the NestJS application. It's quite straightforward how to address the `onRequest` events. However, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right when having to do both at the same time. In order for me to pass the `onCreate` event changes and context to the service layer, I need to get access to the `AppService` class. To do that I need access to the `app` instance that has been created. However, I feel like I'm creating two instances of the `app` (refer to the code). I would like to know if my current my implementation is best to practice or if there is any way it can be improved. Please note I'm a frontend developer so this work is outside my comfort zone. I would like to know the best way to do this, especially if I have to work with more events such as `onUpate`, `onDelete` etc.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { Express } from 'express-serve-static-core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

const server = express();

export const createNestServer = async (expressInstance: Express) => {
  //FIRST APP INSTANCE
  const app = await NestFactory.create(
    AppModule,
    new ExpressAdapter(expressInstance),
  );
  admin.initializeApp();
  return app.init();
};

createNestServer(server)
  .then((v) => console.log('Nest Ready'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('Nest broken', err));

//exporting all onRequest events
export const api = functions.https.onRequest(server);
//exporting the  onUserCreate event
exports.onUserCreate = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{docId}')
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    console.log('Changes are tracked');
    //SECOND APP INSTANCE
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    return app.get(AppService).onCreate(change, context);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have something like a `UsersController` (and others) that handles retrieving, creating, updating the users as part of the NestJS application. Just pass the Express instance (wrapped by the NestJS adapter) to the Cloud Function HTTPS handler (`onRequest`). NestJS will take care of setting up the routes.

```
export const api = functions.https.onRequest(server)
```

```
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UserService) {}

  @Get(':userId')
  async getUser(@Param('userId') id: String) {
    // retrieve user
  }

  @Post()
  async create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    // create a new user
  }

  ...
}

@Module({
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [AppService, UsersService],
  exports: [AppService, UsersService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The `AppService` is a provider registered in the `AppModule`. You could extract it from the `INestApplication` instance.

```
const server = express();
let appService: AppService;

export const createNestServer = async (expressInstance: Express) => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(
    AppModule,
    new ExpressAdapter(expressInstance),
  );
  admin.initializeApp();
  appService = app.get(AppService);
  return app.init();
};
```

Then you could use it within the `onWrite` firestore trigger.

Seems like you are trying to do 2 differents tasks with the same NestJS app. Just let the NestJS (or ExpressJS) app handle the HTTPS requests. And for the `onCreate`, `onWrite` ... triggers implement a different solution. Perhaps don't rely on NestJS to handle these types of triggers.

NestJS personally feels like overkill, you could just use ExpressJS. You wouldn't have to register the `AppService` as a provider and jump through hoops.

Comment: Hey Chrostophe thank you very much for your answer. I do understand it's a bit overkill but I'm also trying to learn the platform in the process. I've posted an answer below, would love to hear your feedback on it and let me know if its a good and acceptable approach. Cheers.

Comment: It's basically as suggested in my answer. The createNestServer returns a Promise<INestApplication>.  Instead of extracting the AppService beforehand you use the already resolved promise and extract and use it on each onWrite trigger notification.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach has allowed me to solve the multiple instatiation issue of the app instance. Hopefully this is a good and acceptable way to do this. Feedback is more than welcome.

```
const server = express();

export const createNestServer = async (expressInstance: Express) => {
  //FIRST APP INSTANCE
  const app = await NestFactory.create(
    AppModule,
    new ExpressAdapter(expressInstance),
  );

  admin.initializeApp();
  return app.init();
};

const main = createNestServer(server);

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(server);

exports.onUserWrite = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{docId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) =>
    main.then((app) => {
      return app.get(AppService).onCreate(change, context);
    }),
  );
```